# Unit Testing of a protected slot

Tags: unit-testing, qt, protected

Hello I tried to implement unit testing for a protected slot
In the testing function I made an object of a class and called a protected of that class using that object
But it gave me an error as follows:

/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/backend.h: In member function ‘void BackendTest::test_initialization()’:
/home/puneet/puneet/office/alkimia/payment/backend/backend.h:70: error: ‘void Backend::initializeUsers(const QStringList&)’ is protected

Comment: What language, framework, etc is that in? I'm familiar with "unit-testing". Is "protected" the name of the programming language you are using?

Comment: qt, I was talking about the protected slot, where slot is a function that is called in response to a particular signal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I usually handle this for tests is to use the following defines:

If the header file for the class you are testing is "myclass.h", where you #include it in the test file, do:

```
#define protected public
#include "myclass.h"
#undef protected
```

This tells the compiler to treat the protected methods as public instead.  You can do the same for private functions.